# Variadic template function with restricted parameters in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm struggling on how to design a function in C++ that does the following:

- The function takes a least two arguments (the type is defined by a template parameter)
- The actual number of arguments can vary (It should also take 5 arguments e.g.)
- All arguments of the function are of the same type
- The first argument of the function is read only
- The function takes the value of the first argument and assigns it to all other arguments

In pseudo code it would kinda look like this:

```
do_stuff(a, b, c, ... n) {
  b = a;
  c = a;
  ...
  n = a;
}
```

What I've came up with so far looks like this:

```
  template <typename... T> void
    do_stuff(const T& in, Args & ... args) {

  }
```

My question is, how can I use variadic parameter packs and make sure that the first argument is never changed and that all arguments are of the same type?

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: ‘*All arguments of the function are of the same type*’ So you only need one template parameter then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by restricting your function's arguments using SFINAE. This implementation uses C++17's fold expressions to avoid having to manually write a recursive call:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename... Args>
std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<T, Args>...> && sizeof...(Args) >= 1>
broadcast(const T& source, Args&... targets)
{
    (targets = ... = source);
}
```

The `enable_if` enforces that `T` and each member of `Args` are the same type, and that there is at least one argument.

<sup>[Demo on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/H90XVm), [Demo on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HgQA9ugIRO7RDC6n)</sup>

---

In C++11, you can instead use a recursive call to implement this efficiently (at the cost of your compile time).

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail
{
    template <typename T>
    void broadcast_impl(const T&) {}

    template <typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, U>::value>::type
    broadcast_impl(const T& source, U& first, Args&... remaining)
    {
        first = source;
        broadcast_impl<T, Args...>(source, remaining...);
    }
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void broadcast(const T& source, T& first, Args&... remaining)
{
    detail::broadcast_impl<T, T, Args...>(source, first, remaining...);
}
```

<sup>[Demo on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/74jfCE)</sup>

As a bonus, here's an SFINAE-free version that introduces an additional level of pointer indirection (because we cannot create an `std::initializer_list` of references)

```
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void broadcast(const T& source, T& first, Args&... targets)
{
    std::initializer_list<T*> ts = { &first, &targets... };
    for (T* ptr : ts)
        *ptr = source;
}
```

<sup>[Demo on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/n-uzpM)</sup>